# Android cannot find symbol DaggerAppComponent Error with no hint to what caused it

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2, android-databinding, dagger

I am getting this error and I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]


> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:checkDebugClasspath UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateSafeArgsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\123\Documents\code\android\deamat\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:generateDebugSources
> Task :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:transformDataBindingBaseClassLogWithDataBindingMergeGenClassesForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: [1] Wrote GeneratedAppGlideModule with: []
warning: View field quantity collides with a variable or import
  file://C:\Users\123\Documents\code\android\deamat\app\src\main\res\layout\product_quantity.xml Line:29
warning: View field totalPrice collides with a variable or import
  file://C:\Users\123\Documents\code\android\deamat\app\src\main\res\layout\screen_cart.xml Line:50
warning: totalPrice is a boxed field but needs to be un-boxed to execute app:currency. This may cause NPE so Data Binding will safely unbox it. You can change the expression and explicitly wrap totalPrice with safeUnbox() to prevent the warning
  file://C:\Users\123\Documents\code\android\deamat\app\src\main\res\layout\screen_cart.xml Line:50
warning: View field category collides with a variable or import
  file://C:\Users\123\Documents\code\android\deamat\app\src\main\res\layout\single_category.xml Line:11
warning: dark is a boxed field but needs to be un-boxed to execute dark ? @android:drawable/selectable_item_gray_background : @android:drawable/selectable_item_light_gray_background. This may cause NPE so Data Binding will safely unbox it. You can change the expression and explicitly wrap dark with safeUnbox() to prevent the warning
C:\Users\123\Documents\code\android\deamat\app\src\main\java\com\deamat\deamat\DeamatApplication.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                       ^
  symbol:   variable DaggerAppComponent
  location: class DeamatApplication
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
5 warnings

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:596)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:114)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 29 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
26 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 21 up-to-date
```

I tried increasing the log output level with

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "1000"
    }
}
```

I also tried adding `--stacktrace` to the command-line options to get more context. I also tried to see if there are problems in my dagger modules.
How can I make android studio help me debug the exact cause?

Comment: Sometimes the problem might not be from Dagger. Clean your project again, Rebuild and lastly *Make Project*. That should show you where the error is.

Comment: `DaggerAppComponent` is a class that gets auto-generated after a build. Often I find, just building again after getting this issue solves this problem.

Comment: Still same error. That didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have an import for `DaggerAppComponent` in your application class? Also you can check if `DaggerAppComponent` is actually generated or not. Just find if the file exists `Ctrl+Shift+N`